# Finding prominent frequencies from FFT

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the prominent peaks in an audio signal (piano recording) using STFT. This is what Ive done so far
 1. Obtain the envelope of the time domain signal
 2. Determine the peaks in the enveloped signal and use them as note onsets
 3. perform FFT for the samples between each 2 consecutive onsets.

Now that I have the FFT, I want to find the peaks corresponding to the notes played... when i try using the `findpeaks` function at some points it says its an empty matrix.

```
clear all;
clear max;
clc;

[song,FS] = wavread('C major.wav');
sound(song,FS);

P = 20000;
N=length(song);                     % length of song
t=0:1/FS:(N-1)/FS;                  % define time period


song = sum(song,2);                        
song=abs(song);
%windowing = hamming(32768); %Windowing function

% Plot time domain signal
figure(1);
          subplot(2,1,1)
          plot(t,3*song)
          title('Wave File')
          ylabel('Amplitude')
          xlabel('Length (in seconds)')
          %ylim([-1.1 1.1])
          xlim([0 N/FS])

%----------------------Finding the envelope of the signal-----------------%
% Gaussian Filter
x = linspace( -1, 1, P);                      % create a vector of P values between -1 and 1 inclusive
sigma = 0.335;                                % standard deviation used in Gaussian formula
myFilter = -x .* exp( -(x.^2)/(2*sigma.^2));  % compute first derivative, but leave constants out
myFilter = myFilter / sum( abs( myFilter ) ); % normalize

% Plot Gaussian Filter
         subplot(2,1,2)       
         plot(myFilter)
         title('Edge Detection Filter')

% fft convolution
myFilter = myFilter(:);                         % create a column vector
song(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;      %zero pad song
myFilter(length(song)) = 0;                     %zero pad myFilter
edges =ifft(fft(song).*fft(myFilter));

tedges=edges(P:N+P-1);                      % shift by P/2 so peaks line up w/ edges
tedges=tedges/max(abs(tedges));                 % normalize

%---------------------------Onset Detection-------------------------------%
% Finding peaks
maxtab = [];
mintab = [];
x = (1:length(tedges));
min1 = Inf;
max1 = -Inf;
min_pos = NaN; 
max_pos = NaN;

lookformax = 1;
for i=1:length(tedges)

    peak = tedges(i:i);
  if peak > max1, 
      max1 = peak;
      max_pos = x(i); 
  end
  if peak < min1, 
      min1 = peak;
      min_pos = x(i); 
  end

  if lookformax
    if peak < max1-0.01
      maxtab = [maxtab ; max_pos max1];
      min1 = peak; 
      min_pos = x(i);
      lookformax = 0;
    end  
  else
    if peak > min1+0.05
      mintab = [mintab ; min_pos min1];
      max1 = peak; 
      max_pos = x(i);
      lookformax = 1;
    end
  end
end
% % Plot song filtered with edge detector          
         figure(2)
         plot(1/FS:1/FS:N/FS,tedges)
         title('Song Filtered With Edge Detector 1')
         xlabel('Time (s)')
         ylabel('Amplitude')
         ylim([-1 1.1])
         xlim([0 N/FS])

         hold on;

         plot(maxtab(:,1)/FS, maxtab(:,2), 'ro')
         plot(mintab(:,1)/FS, mintab(:,2), 'ko')

max_col = maxtab(:,1);
peaks_det = max_col/FS; 
No_of_peaks = length(peaks_det);

song = detrend(song);
%---------------------------Performing FFT--------------------------------%
 for i = 2:No_of_peaks

    song_seg = song(max_col(i-1):max_col(i)-1);
%     song_seg = song(max_col(6):max_col(7)-1);
    L = length(song_seg);    
    NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y

    seg_fft = fft(song_seg,NFFT);%/L;

    N=5;Fst1=50;Fp1=60; Fp2=1040; Fst2=1050;

%     d = fdesign.bandpass('N,Fst1,Fp1,Fp2,Fst2');
%     h = design(d);
%     seg_fft = filter(h, seg_fft);

%     seg_fft(1) = 0;
%     
    f = FS/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
    seg_fft2 = 2*abs(seg_fft(1:NFFT/2+1));
    L5 = length(song_seg);

    figure(1+i)
    plot(f,seg_fft2)
    title('Frequency spectrum of signal')
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    %xlim([0 2500])
    ylabel('|Y(f)|')
    ylim([0 300])

    %[B, IX] = sort(seg_fft2)

    %[points loc] = findpeaks(seg_fft);

    %STFT_out(:,i) = seg_fft2;

    %P=max(seg_fft2)
    [points, loc] = findpeaks(seg_fft2,'THRESHOLD',20)
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) for findpeaks, the meaning of threshold is:

> Specify the threshold height difference between a peak and its
>   neighboring values as a positive real number. findpeaks only returns
>   peaks that exceed their neighbors by at least the value of
>   'THRESHOLD'.

Thus in the line

```
[points, loc] = findpeaks(seg_fft2,'THRESHOLD',20)
```

the value of `20` is probably too large. The algorithm is not selecting any maxima because the condition that a peak maximum should lie \delta(y)=20 above its neighboring points leads it to reject all possible maxima.

You may want to specify `MINPEAKHEIGHT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find peaks of notes onset, I suggest the following steps, which worked for me when trying to find the onset of a beep within a noisy video.

1. extract the signal of the wavfile.read(audio_wav_path) and the correspoinding wavfile.read(piano_note_wav_path).
2. fftconvolve both via scipy.signal (this finds areas of similarity between the audio and the note signals)
3. fft convolve the piano note with itself (this finds the ideal shape if for instance the audio was itself the piano note exactly)
4. correlate the self convolution (3) with the convolution of both (2) (this finds the areas where (2) matches closely with (3), reducing false positive readings of similar notes)
5. make into np arrays and threshold (to only look at really tall peaks) then normalize (to make the numbers you're dealing with more manageable)

Once all this is done if you take the scipy.signal's find_peaks it should give you the peak amplitudes from which you should be able to find the time stamps.

This worked for me as the peak amplitudes weren't one consistent amplitude.
Hope it help!